# Webstorm MAC OSX: Regular expression for backreference is not working in replace field

Tags: regex, replace, webstorm

In WebStorm, I am using Find and Replace functionality with regular expression to replace hexadecimal color code to an upper case equivalent **e.g. #ddd to #DDDDDD**.

Image to show what I tried:
[image]
**Find** field have `#[0-9a-z]{3,6};` regular expression and it finds color codes correctly. **Replace** field have `\U$1\`.

Regular expression is not recognized in the replace field. The tooltip says `Empty string`. I tried with other values too.

I refered PhpStorm's documentation on [Changing case of the characters](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html#change_case) and I believe it should be valid for WebStorm too.

Comment: You have no Group 1, use Group 0: `\U$0`.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that [Webstorm uses Java regular expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html#comment-1391729850):

> WebStorm is the Java-based application, so we use Java engine to process everything, including Regular Expressions.

Java regex does not support `\U` nor `\u`, `\l` or `\L` operators.

**However, you can use them in Notepad++.**

I see you followed the [Webstorm Help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html) that shows an example search and replace with `\stitle="(.*)?"\s*(/>*)` regex and `\U$1` replacement.

The `$1` is a backreference to what has been captured by the first subpattern inside round brackets. Since `#[0-9a-z]{3,6};` has no pairs of unescaped parentheses, `$1` backreference does not point to any text. Instead, use Group 0: `\U$0`.

If you want you can define the first capturing group round the whole pattern: `(#[0-9a-z]{3,6};)` and then use your replacement pattern.

Comment: It worked partially upon using `\U$0`. Now it seems that replacing pattern doesn't recognize `U` to upper case the searched string. The string which gets replaced is `U#ffffff` for hexadecimal color `#ffffff`.

Comment: Then try `(#[0-9a-z]{3,6};)` and your `\U$1` replacement.

Comment: I think the operator is not working as it is not supported by Java regex engine. I tested that in Java and it just does not work either. So, it is not PCRE/ICU based regex here, and you cannot use `\L`/`\U` and `\l`/`\u` operators.